symbol not found error when starting Backstage
Following the IBM MQ Developer tutorial (https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/awb-deploy-ibm-mq-developer-patterns-backstage/) produces this error when running the yarn dev command:
[backend]:  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
[backend]:         ^
[backend]: 
[backend]: Error: dlopen(/Users/shreeya/test-backstage/node_modules/isolated-vm/out/isolated_vm.node, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN2v815ValueSerializer8Delegate16GetSharedValueIdEPNS_7IsolateENS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE'

A web page is created but says:
TypeError
Load failed
Call Stack
No stack trace is available for this error!

I am using the following versions of node and npm:
node = v22.10.0
npm = 10.9.0

To solve this issue, you must be using either Node 18 or 20 as mentioned in the Backstage documentation.
nvm use 18 


https://backstage.io/docs/releases/v1.19.0#highlights says The supported versions of Node.js are now v18 and v20.

Considering that the latest version is 1.32, that restraint is buried. I only realised when I opened the Backstage package.json.
